# Adding new column using awk command adds the whole content to the last?

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to append a current date field using awk in every line to my pipe separated content. Instead of what is intended, the whole 16 columns are getting appended to the 17th (new) position. I tried changing things but did not help. I think there is some basic mistake. Can I be helped here?

```
 awk ' BEGIN{FS="|";}
{
    $17=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y");

    printf("%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10,
     $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17);

}' /Users/temp/dispn/content3.txt | less > /Users/temp/dispn/content4.txt
```

Input(16 fields):

```
EX122YED| Buy online |example.com/EX122YED |example.com/EX122YED.jpg|White|new|00.00|in stock|XYZ|Accessories|Accessories|Male|30-40|y|EX122YED|0.0
```

My Output

```
EX122YED| Buy online |example.com/EX122YED |example.com/EX122YED.jpg|White|new|00.00|in stock|XYZ|Accessories|Accessories|Male|30-40|y|EX122YED|0.0|EX122YED| Buy online |example.com/EX122YED |example.com/EX122YED.jpg|White|new|00.00|in stock|XYZ|Accessories|Accessories|Male|30-40|y|EX122YED|0.0
```

Intended (17 fields):

```
EX122YED| Buy online |example.com/EX122YED |example.com/EX122YED.jpg|White|new|00.00|in stock|XYZ|Accessories|Accessories|Male|30-40|y|EX122YED|0.0|06-22-2014
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem here is that the `$(date +"%d-%m-%Y");` in the script is interpreted as `$0` because `bash` is not expanding it. To prevent this you can define the `awk` script in double quotes like this:

```
awk "{print \$0\"|\"$(date +\"%d-%m-%Y\")}"
```

which requires all sort of escaping `$` and `"` characters to make it work.

If you do not need to use `awk` but could also use `sed` you could use:

```
sed "s/$/|$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")/"
```

Comment: thanks, it works. The first solution with escaping characters.

Comment: @NihalSharma Another way without escaping characters would be to simply put the date command outside of the awk quotes `$17="'$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")'";`

Answer (score 2):

Assign the date to a variable and print it with the entire line,

```
awk -F'|' -v var=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y") '{print $0,var}' OFS="|"
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo 'EX122YED| Buy online |example.com/EX122YED |example.com/EX122YED.jpg|White|new|00.00|in stock|XYZ|Accessories|Accessories|Male|30-40|y|EX122YED|0.0' | awk -F'|' -v var=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y") '{print $0,var}' OFS="|"
EX122YED| Buy online |example.com/EX122YED |example.com/EX122YED.jpg|White|new|00.00|in stock|XYZ|Accessories|Accessories|Male|30-40|y|EX122YED|0.0|22-06-2014
```

If you want `month-date-year` format then change the `date` command to `date +"%m-%d-%Y"`